# How to find struct's fields that aren't assigned

Tags: go

```
type Student struct{
    Name string
    No int
}

student:=Student{
    Name:"Lily",
}
```

So, how can I know student's field "No" isn't assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way to check if some value is set or not without manually comparing each and every field of a struct.

That's the reason why, in `stdlib` many packages have methods `New...`.

For example `bufio.NewWriter()`, where the author of the package takes care of initializing the struct with some sane default values according to one's own use case.

```
// NewStudent returns new Student instance
func NewStudent() *Student {
    return &Student{Name: "defaultName", No: 7}
}
```

Even though `Student` type is exported, your package users are supposed to use `New...` to use any struct.

There is also another way one can manage this problem, but it maybe too much of stretch for many programs, but you can read about them [here](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2014/01/self-referential-functions-and-design.html) and [here](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/17/functional-options-for-friendly-apis).

Answer (score 4):

If you define `No` as integer, then if it's not assigned golang will set it to `0`(default value) which is sometimes can be confusing based on the purpose you use it(for example, if `0` is a valid value for `No`).

If you really want to check whether `Student.No` is assigned or not. I think it's best to use **Pointer**.

```
type Student struct{
    Name string
    No *int
}

student:= Student{
    Name:"Lily",
}

if student.No == nil {
    fmt.Println("student.No is not defined")
}

student2 := Student{
    Name: "Bob",
    No: func(i int) *int{ return &i}(5),
}

if student2.No != nil {
    fmt.Printf("student.No is %d\n", *student2.No)
}
```

Here is the code : https://play.golang.org/p/_lhbQcDA_eb

Answer (score 2):

This field will have the zero value for that data type. In this case a 0. Your check would look like this:

```
student.No == 0
```

This might seem a bit strange at first. But in this case a `0` as a number does not make sense as a valid student number.

Answer (score 2):

Every data type in Go has it's own "zero value". So, in `No` (`number`) case, it's `0`. You can check if the value of `No` is `0`.

More info here ->  https://tour.golang.org/basics/12

Comment: I would say default value instead of zero value, where for integers is `0`, for strings double quotes (`""`), for pointers `nil`, etc

Comment: The go tour page itself calls it "zero value" -> https://tour.golang.org/basics/12

Comment: @mchar and Andy: not only go tour, but the spec also calls it ["the zero value"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)

Comment: I guess it's the same thing in other words. Good to clarify this.

Comment: Better use pointer. It is not enough to only check whether the value of `No` is `0`.  It will not work if the `Student.No` is assigned by `0`

Answer (score 2):

You to define the variable as a pointer variable

```
type Student struct{
    Name string
    No *int
}

student:=Student{
    Name:"Lily",
}
```

In this case if you do

```
if student.No==nil{
    fmt.Println("Yes I'm unassigned")
}
```

it'll print

```
Yes I'm unassigned
```

We can use this technique while unmarshalling json, to find out whether a field is provided or not and while scanning a nullable value form database. To get the value back you have to use

```
*student.NO
```